# Java print service API: send job to printer spool?

Tags: java, printing, spool

I am using Java print service API to select `PrintService` and then pass it to `JasperReport`'s `JRPrintServiceExporter`. The basic idea is to just send a document to the provided `PrintService`. It is actually using `java.awt.print.PrinterJob.print()`.

It seems like you cannot send a print job to a printer that has `PrinterIsAcceptingJobs.NOT_ACCEPTING_JOBS` attribute, when it is offline or powered off  If I sent a job to it, I would get a `PrinterException` because it is not accepting jobs.

Is it possible to print to a "NOT_ACCEPTING_JOBS" printer? In actual operating system this works, the job is queued in the pool. How to achieve the same effect using Java print service API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are trying to solve is similar to [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6525150). The problem seems to be that Java 1.5 and 1.6 looks at the wrong flags (printer instead of queue).

A solution that seems to work is to use the ForceAcceptPrintService described [in this forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1287312&start=0). Alternatively,
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471513/741249) mentions a workaround using byte manipulation but I didn't try that solution myself.